# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript

Делаю проект по парадигме ООП, не могу понять почему не находит и не добавляет класс для того чтобы модальное окно стало видимым, выдает такую ошибку вот в этом фрагменте кода

```
openPopup() {
    this._selectedPopup.classList.add('popup_opened');
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this._handleEscKey);
  };
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')**

```
class Popup {
  constructor (selectorPopup) {
    this._selectorPopup = document.querySelector(selectorPopup);
  };
/* Открытие модального окна */
  openPopup() {
    this._selectedPopup.classList.add('popup_opened');
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this._handleEscKey);
  };
/* Закрытие модального окна */
  closePopup() {
    this._selectorPopup.classList.remove('popup_opened');
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this._handleEscKey);
  };
/* Закрытие модального окна кнопкой 'Escape' */
  _handleEscKey() {
    if (evt.key = 'Escape') {
      this.closePopup;
    };
  };
/* Постановка слушателей для закрытия модального окна по клику на "Overlay" и крестик */
  setEventListeners() {
    this._selectorPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('popup_opened')) {
        this.closePopup;
      };
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('popup__close-icon')) {
        this.closePopup;
      };
    });
  };
};
class PopupWithForm extends Popup {
  constructor (selectorPopup) {
    super(selectorPopup);
    //this._handleFormSubmit = handleFormSubmit;
  };
/* Получение значений из полей ввода */
  _getInputValues() {
    this._inputList = this._selectorPopup.querySelectorAll('.popup__input');
    this._newInputValues = {};
    this._inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
      this._newInputValues = inputElement.value
    });
    console.log(this._newInputValues);
  };
/* Сброс значений полей ввода */
  resetForm() {
    this._selectorPopup.reset();
  };
/* Добавление сброса формы в родительский метод закрытия модального окна*/
  closePopup() {
    super.closePopup();
    resetForm();
  };
/* Установка слушателей */
  setEventListeners() {
    super.setEventListeners();
    this._formSelector = this._selectorPopup.querySelector('.popup__input-container');
    this._formSelector.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
    });
    //this._handleFormSubmit(this._getInputValues());
    }
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется проблема не там где вы указали, а тут:

```js
setEventListeners() {
    this._selectorPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('popup_opened')) {
        this.closePopup;
      };
      if (evt.target.classList.contains('popup__close-icon')) {
        this.closePopup;
      };
    });
  };
```

Вы в `addEventListener` в стрелочной функции не передаёте как аргумент `evt`, потому он и не знает что такое `evt.target` и считает его за `undefined` и соответвенно ругается, что у `undefined` не может найти `classList`

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/d294ceb40db7a646d2e877db49ab5f6e
скриншот с самой ошибкой, то что вы сказали, исправил, ошибка все равно осталась, Вообще не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: @Default Если будет возможность опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный рабочий код, где воспроизводится ошибка. Потому что так очень трудно сказать что именно не так, ведь если бы `document.querySelector` не находил бы сам элемент, то он долженибыл бы вернуть `null` и ошибка была бы вообще другая

Comment: @EzioMercerer, Вам удобно будет посмотреть работу на ГитХабе?
https://github.com/Kamil-Kalandarov/mesto-project/tree/feature/mesto-update
В ветке feature/mesto-update

Comment: Если код публичный то можете опубликовать свой репозиторий тут [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/repositories), чтобы не скачивать

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fast-ikqjm5

Comment: @Default попробовал у себя и у вас, никак сайт не реагирует, только ошибки webpack. Но есть пару замечаний на счёт кода (вряд ли исправит ошибку но всё же). Везде где вы пишгите `this.closePopup;` надо писать `this.closePopup();`. Там где вы написали `if (evt.key = 'Escape')` `if` не имеет смысла т.к. вы присваиваете, а не сравниваете и в этой `_handleEscKey` функции так же надо принимать `evt` как аргумент. Попробуйте вместо `super.openPopup();` вызывать `this.openPopup();`. На данном этапе всё что могу вам посоветовать - это написать `debugger` в `openPopup` и проследить за всеми переменными

Comment: ВебПак работает, по крайней мере у меня, а в СэндБоксе, да, ошибки выдает. debugger делал, не нашел ничего я, Я новичок в JS, обучаюсь только, но с этой ошибкой сижу почти неделю уже

Comment: Попробуйте сделать другие исправления, о которых я говорил, может поможет